# Change button color when range change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("[type=range]").change(function(){
if(!$('#changetoyello').hasClass('yellow'))
$('#changetoyello').addClass('yellow');
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <li>
      Apply Credits1: 
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
        name="discount_credits1" id="discount_credits" 
        />
    </li>
    <li>
      Apply Credits2: 
      <input type="range" min="0" max="100" 
        name="discount_credits2" id="discount_credits" 
        />
    </li>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changetoyello" onclick="resetfilter()" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is my code : There is two range slider addede whenever i change anyone slider so my button color should change into yellow
The problem is i just want to change my button color into 
yellow whenever i change the range

Comment: Can you please update your code above to remove the error?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved by introducing the following CSS:

```
.btn.yellow {

  background:yellow;
  border-color:yellow;

  color:black; /* Make text readable on yellow background */
}
```

Here's a working code snippet demonstrating the solution in action:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("[type=range]").change(function() {
    if (!$('#changetoyello').hasClass('yellow'))
      $('#changetoyello').addClass('yellow');
  });
});

/* Remove yellow theme when clicked */
$('#changetoyello').click(function() {
  $(this).removeClass('yellow');
});
```

```css
.btn.yellow {
  background:yellow;
  border-color:yellow;
  color:black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- jQuery library -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <li>
    Apply Credits1:
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="discount_credits1" id="discount_credits" />
  </li>
  <li>
    Apply Credits2:
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" name="discount_credits2" id="discount_credits" />
  </li>
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="changetoyello" class="btn btn-info" role="button">Link Button</a>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Update

To remove the yellow color from the button when clicked, add the following to your script:

```
$('#changetoyello').click(function() {

  /* Remove yellow theme when clicked */
  $(this).removeClass('yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks bro. can u please do little update on it. when i click on button after its color changed by slider it should back to default color. it will be possible